# do I need the CMake install step when packaging with CPack?

Tags: cmake, cpack

Reading the cmake/cpack documentation, it is stated that CPack will generate an installer which *contains everything installed via CMake’s INSTALL command*.

However, do I need the `cmake --build . --target install` in the my following packaging command line sequence ?

```
 - cmake ..
 - cmake --build .
 - cmake --build . --target install
 - cmake --build . --target package
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packaging is an alternative to installation.

If you want create a package, you do **not need** to execute `install` target.

(But installation may be implicitely performed by 'package' target).

Comment: However, if packaging is an alternative to installation, how to inform  `cmake` that we are in an `install` or a `package` context using only the install command ? For instance, if I want to package my application in a MacOS bundle. Should I introduce an option such as `BUILD_BUNDLE` which will allow to separate the logic between installing and packaging and set it to `ON` prior doing a `make_package` command ?

Comment: Usually, CMake code doesn't depend on whether the project will be installed or packaged. But if your project depends on that, you need to **separately configure** (run `cmake`) the project for packaging and for installation.